# Is there a better Google Sheets rounding/floating point error workaround?

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, rounding-error

I have a Sheet that gives me a rounding error:

[image: spreadsheet segment showing rounding error]

Rounding 0.415 to 2 places should result in 0.42, which it does when given the number directly. But the red line gives 0.41. The intermediate result before rounding is slightly less than 0.415, as shown in the second line.

The green line shows a workaround, which I guess I'll have to use throughout, unless anyone can suggest a better one. Any offers?

Comment: this is more of a floating point issue than a rounding one right?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ROUNDUP((170.625-168.55)*0.2, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that would round up everything, so even 0.4100001 would round to 0.42.